# Is it possible to have a test soft fail in Perl?

Tags: perl, testing

Is it possible to have a soft fail of a test in Perl? by soft fail I mean the test fails, but it will not cause the test suite to fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *may* help ... You can mark a block of tests as 'TODO' like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

ok(1);

TODO: {
    local $TODO = 'is_odd() implementation still flakey';

    is( is_odd(3), 1, '3 is odd' );
};


done_testing();


sub is_odd {
  return rand() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Whether the tests in the TODO block pass or fail will not affect the result for the script.  However if the tests *do* pass, the summary output from `prove` will tell you which test passed 'unexpectedly'.  The verbose output from `prove -v` will give full diagnostic details for all the tests including failing TODO tests.

Comment: I wonder if I can create todo tests with Test::Builder... not really what I asked though.

Comment: Yes, I realised it wasn't directly addressing your question.  An approach we take at $work is to flag some test scripts as 'skipped'.  A 1-line addition at the start of the script causes it to bail out early and not 'break the build'.  Of course that doesn't tell us if the script _would have_ passed.